# Convert YYYYMMDD into YYYY-MM-DD and HHMMSS into HH:MM:SS for candlestick plotting

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've been trying to find an answer for 4 hours, but no luck. Any help will be very appreciable.

Goal: convert 20170103 into 2017-01-03 and 022100 into 02:21:00 for candlestick plotting

```
date_int = 20170103
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[date_int]*10})
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d'))
print(df['date'])


time_int = 020100
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[time_int]*10})
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%H:%M:%S'))
print(df['time'])
```

but the second code shows 'invalid token' error.

And I also notice that this code performs very slow. If there is a more efficient way, please, let me know. Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: The `format='%H:%M:%S'` is incorrect, you should be using `format='%H%M%S'`

Comment: And you don't need a lambda function for this, use `df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y%m%d')`

Comment: Invalid token because you have zero in front. Make it `time_int = '020100'` as string. THis is answer for invalid token error. and then `apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%H%M%S'))`

Comment: @yatu, thank you for your comment, but I still can't figure out how to apply what you suggest in the code. Can you show an example code? Thank you.

Comment: @webDev, Thank you for your comment, even after applying the change you suggest, I still have the same  'invalid token' error. Any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comments, you have a few things wrong here. Firstly as mentioned, the used format in your second example is wrong. Your data has the format `'%H%M%S'`, so it is the one you need to specify in the argument.

When using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), the specified format indicates the actual data format so that it can be correctly parsed.
In order to further modify it, you need to add [`Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
date_int = 20170103
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[date_int]*10})
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

     date
0  2017-01-03
1  2017-01-03
2  2017-01-03
3  2017-01-03
4  2017-01-03
5  2017-01-03
6  2017-01-03
7  2017-01-03
8  2017-01-03
9  2017-01-03
```

So similarly for your second example you need:

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%H%M%S').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: The YYYY-MM-DD works great, but HH:MM:SS, stilling showing me the same invalid token error. Because it starts with 0? Any insight will be very appreciable.

Comment: @mocs turn it to a string instead, use `'020100'`

Comment: Invalid because zero infront, just make that as string as I suggested in my answer and comment above on your post

Comment: @yatu, works great. Thank you so much. I've been fighting for this last 4 hours. Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here, Based on my comment above. (for Invalid token error, make it string surrounded by single quote or double)

```
time_int = '020100'
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[time_int]*10})
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%H%M%S'))
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.time
print(df['time'])
```

**Output:**

```
0    02:01:00
1    02:01:00
2    02:01:00
3    02:01:00
4    02:01:00
5    02:01:00
6    02:01:00
7    02:01:00
8    02:01:00
9    02:01:00
```

Comment: this works. Thank you for much for your help. Many many thank you.

Comment: Invalid token error was just because you had zero in front which is not a valid integer literal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the question and it looks like the original question was two test cases to get code using the panda package debugged.  The comment that the code ran slowly suggests that a file of dates and times is being read.  Given that candlestick plots could be used with a datetime object, perhaps this all could be solved simply.

Reading each line pull the date and time out as a single string, say '20170103 022100'.
Use datetime to parse directly to a datetime object.

```
import datetime as dt
ts='20170103    022100'
result=dt.datetime.strptime(ts,'%Y%m%d %H%M%S')
```

What's nice about strptime is that the single space in the format represents whitespace, so the multiple spaces in the string parse correctly.

Hope that simplifies things.